# How to rename a function in IDA Pro?

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, decompiling, ida

I have a library (libms.so) which contains a function `Java_com_miar_cpo_Xml_makefile`. I want to rename this function to `Java_com_mypack_cls_Xml_makefile` and save changes in IDA Pro. I want only to rename function name so how to do that? This is for android native code reverse engineering. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Move your mouse on the function name, press "n" on the keyboard and enter Java_com_mypack_cls_Xml_makefile and then "Ok".

Comment: It doesn't help, it only rename for IDA viewer, not actual function name in the library file.